# Hotkey to run a batch file to hibernate computer

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, hibernate, hotkeys

I'm working on trying to get a shortcut to work to where I press my hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to run a batch file that hibernates my computer in 4 minutes.  The batch file works and the shortcut, when I double press that, it also runs the batch file and still works.  The only problem is the hotkeys are not starting the shortcut.

Here is the setup that I have for this

[image: Image of Set up]

Comment: Have you attempted the key to `start cmd.exe D:\...\...\*.bat`? Try that. (Obviouly the path being the above mentioned.

Comment: Everything works besides the hotkey for the shortcut.  I placed the shortcut with the assigned shortcut in both desktop and start menu and it will only work if I have windows explorer open to the startmenu which I want to be able to use the hotkey at anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**: I tested it moving a shortcut *sequentially* to different folders and surprisingly it works only in following folders (might not be complete):

- Desktop:  `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
- Common Desktop: `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`
- Common Start Menu: `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`
- Common Programs: `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- *Accessories*: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories`

Moreover, I had to open ***Properties* of a moved shortcut** to

- **refresh the hotkey** for the shortcut by setting it to anything else and then back to final hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and
- **change *shortcut target*** (only in some of folders mentioned above)

  - from `"D:\bat files\my Test Script.bat"`
  - to `cmd /c "D:\bat files\my Test Script.bat"`

**FYI**, I'm on ***Windows 8.1* 64 bit**:

```
==> ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

==> set CommonProgramFiles
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

==>
```

**Original answer** based on [**Shortcut key for shortcut does not work**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/134552/shortcut-key-for-shortcut-does-not-work) Microsoft article:

> *Symptoms*
>
> You are unable to run a shortcut by pressing its shortcut key.
>
> *Cause*
>
> Shortcut keys work only for **shortcuts on the desktop or in the Start
>   menu hierarchy**.
>
> *Resolution*
>
> Make sure that the shortcuts for which you want to use shortcut keys
>   are on **the desktop**, on the **Start menu**, or in the **Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs** folder.
>
> *More Information*
>
> **Shortcut keys work differently depending on the location of the
>   shortcut**. If the shortcut is on the desktop or in the Start menu
>   hierarchy, you can use its shortcut key to start the assigned program,
>   or switch to the program if it is already running.
>
> If the shortcut is not on the desktop or in the Start menu hierarchy,
>   you cannot use its shortcut key to start the assigned program, but you
>   can use its shortcut key to switch to the assigned program if it is
>   already running.
>
> NOTE: Shortcut keys may not work for some programs. For example,
>   shortcut keys do not work for items on the Quick Launch bar.

Comment: I got it to work only if I have the file explorer to be open in Windows\Start Menu\Programs folder and still doesn't work on the desktop unless I have the actual properties windows open

Comment: So i edited your target line to /k instead of /c and the output for me was `D:\Programs\batch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file` and the line that is in my batch file is `START cmd.exe /c "ECHO The computer will hibernate in 4 minutes!! :) & ping -n 240 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1 && shutdown /h /f"`

Comment: Shortcut target `cmd /c "D:\bat files\my Test Script.bat"` (note properly escaped items!)

Comment: @RayceNeal I have approved  your edit although… If you set a shortcut target field to `cmd /C command` or `cmd.exe /C command` then Windows system would change it to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c command` immediately after clicking `Apply` button. To be accurate, `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` here is evaluated `%comspec%`.

Answer (score 0):

As @josefZ  mentioned before in this thread, it should be in specific folder + not all shortcut combinations work. For example I tried firstly the "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd> " it did NOT work. But simple button like <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Num1</kbd> worked perfectly.